# substitute comma+space between word and digit

Tags: r

I have:

```
x<- c("20% cotton 30% textile 50% other", "75.5% plastic 24.5% other")
```

How can i change this to the

```
c("20% cotton, 30% textile, 50% other", "75.5% plastic, 24.5% other")
```

?

gsub("[[:alpha:]] ", ", ", y) don't work because "eat" last symbol in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option based on the  pattern is to match the one or more spaces (`+`) followed by the digit (`\\d`) captured as a group (`(...)`), and in the `replacement`, insert the `,` followed by a space and the  backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
gsub(" +(\\d)", ", \\1", x)
#[1] "20% cotton, 30% textile, 50% other" "75.5% plastic, 24.5% other"
```